# what is keep alive timer and how to implement it

Tags: c#, tcp, keep-alive

how can i implement Keep alive timer for TCP connection..
my server closes TCP every 3 seconds. accordingly no other data is being recieved by Server.
I can keep this connection alive by:-

```
1. Sending some data continusly with that 3 seconds.(my requirment is not suitable with this).
2. can i use  TCP keep alive here?. does TCP keep alive means that TCP connection would be there even if server closes it?
```

here is my code

```
   public TCPStreamDevice(string RemoteIPAddress, int RemotePort, string SourceIPAddress, int SourcePortNo)


        {
                mIpAddress = RemoteIPAddress;
                mPort = RemotePort;

                mClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                System.Net.IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(SourceIPAddress), SourcePortNo);

                               mClient.Bind(LocalEndPoint);

                mDataReceivedCallback = new AsyncCallback(DataReceivedTCPCallback_Handler);
                mBuffer = new byte[1024];
                Description = new DeviceDescription();
            }

and in handler i have ..





     private void DataReceivedTCPCallback_Handler(IAsyncResult ar)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                        int bytesReceived = client.EndReceive(ar);

                        if (bytesReceived > 0)
                        {
                          to know transport level errors
                            //EngineInterface.reponseReceived(mBuffer, false);

                            ReceiveCallBackFunc(mBuffer, bytesReceived);

                            client.BeginReceive(mBuffer, 0, 1024, SocketFlags.None, DataReceivedTCPCallback_Handler, client);
                        }
                        else
                        {
    //disconnect   
    /* whrn there is no datapacket  means no TCP connection is alive now(how can i keep tCp alive here) */

    }
```

i want to continue my communication with server(though server had closed the connection).so i need to re-initiate the TCP connection or KEEP ALIVE would work here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add TCP Keepalive behavior to a socket using SO_KEEPLIVE option. Basically, if the other end (peer) dies, then the socket would send a train of keepalives (I think 3) and if hte peer does not respond (which it would not, if it died), then the socket would close the connection and free up the resources associated with teh conneciton.

Comment: so with this can the client communicates with the server even is TCP is closed by server?

Comment: No, if the TCP server closes the connection (due to its application logic), then keepalive cannot do anything. Keepalive has only one purpose -- if the connection becomes idle, then it verifies that the peer still is alive. If the peer is not alive, then TCP keepalive would simply tell teh socket and the socket will close the connection.

Comment: thanx for the clarification manoj..so all i can do is to re-initate the TCP connection with server...isnt it?

Comment: Yes. If you can modify the TCP server to not close the connection till the client has done sending data, then that would help too. You can always have client close the connection AND TCP server implement the keepalive. SO, if the client goes away, then the TCP server can close the connection and freeup the resource.

Comment: i m not supposed to play with TCP server.. TCP needs to be close from server after 3 sec(part of requirment).

Comment: In that case, yes. You would need to re-initiate the TCP connection.

Comment: you mean after every 3 seconds?? is it good design to re-initiate TCP connection again and again?

Comment: Well,, if the server closes teh connection after 3 seconds, then the client does not have much option -- if the client is not done communicating with the server in those 3 seconds, then it has to re-initiate the connection. What is the application trying to do?

Comment: we send commands(protocol based) from windows UI(client) to one hardware(server)..and to that commands hardware send back the response,